# Iterating through dictionary inside class object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, dictionary

I have a class:

```
    class Quizer {
        // construct new quiz for unique user
        constructor(quizObj) {
            this.quiz = quizObj;
            this.currentQuestionNum = 0;
            this.userSelections = [];
        }
        ...

    buttonAction(setup) {
        //var text = this.quiz.question1.question; <-- //works
        var text = this.quiz[currentQuestionNum].question; // doesnt work
    }
}
```

That is constructed here:

```
var quiz = new Quizer(questionObjects);
```

Where questionObjects is:

```
var questionObjects = {
    question1: {
        question: "Darwin explained his theory of evolution in a book called?",
        choices: [
            "this is the correct answer, choose me!",
            "On the Origin of Species",
            "Survival of the Fittest"
        ],
        correctAnswer: "On the Origin of Species"
    },

    question2: {
    ...
    }
}
```

In buttonAction, my goal is to iterate through questionObjects and get each question. Can someone help me with the syntax?

Comment: Why don't push all questions into an array? Then, you will be able to iterate through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this

```
for(var key in questionObjects){
    // The following gives you the question for the current key
    questionsObjects[key].question
}
```

As it is stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can
>   be executed.

Comment: This will work if questionObjects only contains questions. If it has other obects, you need a condition.

Comment: Good catch, but in this case I think that the `questionObjects` contains only questions. Yeah I know that's an assumption, but I think that's the case.